# Cross checking information against Database

Tags: java, database

I'm trying to make a login program, and I need to cross reference the username/password in the GUI to the database, I currently have code, but it just says "Incorrect Username/Password!", to the same amount of people in the database. Any help with actually making it work will be great. My code is as below.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.sql.*;

public class Login extends JFrame {

  JTextField _username = new JTextField(10);
  JPasswordField _password = new JPasswordField(10);

  JButton _login = new JButton("Login");
  JButton _exit = new JButton("Exit");

  Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
  Dimension screenSize = kit.getScreenSize();
  int screenHeight = (int)screenSize.getHeight();
  int screenWidth = (int)screenSize.getWidth();

  public Login() {
    super("Login to panel");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2,1,1));

    add(new JLabel("Username:"));
    add(_username);

    add(new JLabel("Password:"));
    add(_password);

    add(_login);
      _login.addActionListener(new LoginListener());
    add(_exit);
      _exit.addActionListener(new ExitListener());

    setSize(250, 100);
    //setLocation(screenWidth/3, screenHeight/3);
    setLocation(500, 400);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Login();
  }

  public class LoginListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Connection con;
      Statement stmt;
      ResultSet rs;

      try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:collegesys","root","0blivi0n");

        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM main");
        PreparedStatement loginTime = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE `main` WHERE ID = ?");

        while(rs.next()) {
          if(_username.getText() == rs.getObject("username") && _password.getText() == rs.getObject("password")) {
            dispose();
            new Panel();
          } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Username/Password!");
          }
        }

      } catch(SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
      } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  public class ExitListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      dispose();
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `==` to compare strings; use `.equals`: Java 101.

Comment: In no way does this help my programs functionality?

Comment: @NathanKreider Weird, because it's how you're comparing the username and password, and it won't work with ==. Without further info, not much else we can do. It's also grossly inefficient to go through the entire user database when you already have data on which you can select.

Answer (score 0):

Based in the description of your problem, you're bring records from your database so i made two changes

First do not compare string with `==` compare with `equals` function

Second compare this strings ignoring the case by bring the two string to lower or upper something like this

```
 if(_username.getText().toLowerCase().equals(rs.getObject("username").toLowerCase()) && _password.getText().toLowerCase().equals(rs.getObject("password").toLowerCase())
```

Third as I say i trully don't understand what you're trying to achieve but why you just tried to create your query with the parameters instead of bring all the records and loop through them??

Comment: nope, doesn't work. I'm also trying to make the program log in? I need it to cross reference the database, if the textfield's are the same as an entry in the database, it will login. But nothing will work for me.

Comment: and are you sure that username and passwor exit's in the database?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I'm viewing the database, while entering the details. I've also tried many different usernames and passwords.

Comment: I will changed the query and passing the parameters of your textfields, if tha query bring you records let him log into the application